# Creating a git branch for previous commits: what's the best way to do it?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

Imagine the following:

- A bunch of related commits are done on a 'development' branch
- These commits should have actually been done to a 'feature_x' branch
- The 'feature_x' branch should be merged into the 'development' branch

**Graphed example:**

*Current situation:*

```
development (HEAD) A--B--C--D--E
```

*Desired situation:*

```
development         A--B
                        \
feature_x                C--D--E
```

**How do I create this feature branch, group these previous commits into the branch, and make the 'development' branch look like no individual commits have been done to it?**

Comment: I don't really understand your scenario. Could you maybe illustrate with some simple `a -- b -- c` type commit "graphs"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: how to move some commits to new branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168370/git-how-to-move-some-commits-to-new-branch)

Comment: also possible duplicate of [How to move the current working branch to master branch in git](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3168370/11343)

Comment: Remember, branches are just pointers to commits. If you're not actually changing the history (you're not - those graphs are the same), all you're doing is moving those pointers around, which can generally be done just with `git branch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need much to to that:

```
git checkout devel
git checkout -b feature_x
# now devel and feature_x refer to commit E
git branch -f devel <hash of commit B>
# now you're still on feature_x, but devel is at commit B
```

Comment: The third command renames devel; I think you mean `-f` not `-m`.

Answer (score 0):

```
A--B--C--D--E(dev branch)
\
 \
   F--G(feature branch)
```

I assume you want to become like this

```
A--(dev branch)
\
 \
   F--G--B--C--D--E(feature branch)
```

You can use `git rebase` to do this

on the HEAD of dev branch
create a temp branch for rebasing purpose

```
git branch temp
git rebase feature_branch
```

move your devbranch to commit A

```
git checkout dev_branch
git reset --hard <shasum of A>
```

move your feature branch to commit E and delete temp branch

```
git checkout feature_branch
git reset --hard <shasum of E>
git branch -D temp
```