# How do I move recent (but not latest) commits to a new branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, revision-history

i.e. how do I go from

```
master : A-B-C-D-E-F-G
```

to

```
master: A-B-E-F-G
           \
feature:    C-D
```

Obviously its now clear that CD should have been in a feature branch, as that change is now delayed.

This is a subtly different issue to the others I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168370/git-how-to-move-some-commits-to-new-branch) and [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/how-can-i-move-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Comment: That's (currently) three viable answers. Any advantages to each?  I quite like @larsmans cherry pick solution as not requiring rebasing

Comment: But it does require rebasing...

Comment: ah yes. Its does doesn't it. Slaps self on head. So which do I try 1st??? Or are they all equivalents?

Comment: Now that I have reviewed what `--onto` does, I have to admit, I think R0MANARMY's answer is actually just barely superior, despite that mine has more votes. The only real difference is that my version (using `-i` for interactive rebase) requires you to manually select commits C an D for removal, whereas the `--onto` version does that automatically in one command line. As to the third answer that was deleted, it was fine but more long-winded. (Although I liked the backup idea it mentioned, which I have used myself before.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes you either haven't pushed *master* or you're the only person working on the project (in which case it doesn't really matter).  If you have pushed *master* and someone else pulled your changes, you'll need to communicate with them to make sure they update their repositories appropriately.

```
                                  # Assuming you're on master
git branch <feature> <D>          # Create a branch named <feature> at commit <D>
git rebase --onto <B> <D> master  # Transplant branch
```

Git [rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) documentation has a pretty good graphical explanation of what `rebase --onto` does.

---

If you want to avoid a `rebase` altogether, you should be able to do

```
git branch <feature> <D>          # Create a branch named <feature> at commit <D>
git revert <D>                    # undo D
git revert <C>                    # undo C
```

This will result in a history like this

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-!D-!C
      ^           ^
   feature      master
```

Anyone who checks out *master*, will see code as if commits *C* and *D* never happened, you'll just have a couple of [reverts](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) in your history.  That's the preferred way of backing changes out of a branch that has been pushed.

Comment: going with the revert version - the branch has been pushed, so not rewriting history is a major+.

Comment: The revert part of the answer was just a lucky guess at what you were looking for.  You should include that you're looking for an answer not involving a `rebase` in the question.

Comment: I didn't fully grok its significance until you'd pointed out the dangers if I had pushed master: by which time you'd already answered :-) Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Starting at the `HEAD` (G) of `master`:

```
git branch feature D  # Create new branch at D.
git rebase -i B       # Use interactive rebase to remove C D from master.
```